# How to publish nodejs website

Tags: node.js, web-services, angularjs, web, dns

As I have no experience with website publishing I was wondering with how do you publish a AngularJS (front end) + NodeJS (backend) website on some domain. I have researched into some of companies such as WindowsAzzure , AWS and Softlayer but am still not sure. I have already bought the domain from godaddy but how do I run my server instance on these web services and point it to my domain?

Any help will be highly appreciated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend heroku as an application host and it does node out the box

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs

It would be best if you used git, then you can push your site to the heroku remote host

you can also add in your domain https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

but you also get a free one in at 'name'.herokuapp.com

This is also free so long as you come in under the usage theshhold, Should it become a successful app then you can scale out the resource

I have no association with heroku, other than hosting my own node apps on it